# How to make a SOAP request using FRENDS?

Tags: soap, frends

How do I do a SOAP request using [FRENDS](https://frends.com/) platform?

Comment: I didn't find `frends` tag, can someone with enough reputation add it to my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soap messages are normal http messages, that contain soap messages (xml strings) as a body. Therefore you can use normal 
[HttpRequest](https://github.com/FrendsPlatform/Frends.Web#httprequest) task and send soap message, including soap envelope, in the body.

For soap 1.2 you need to use to http headers: `Content-Type: application/soap+xml` and `charset=utf-8`.

full disclosure: I work in a team that made FRENDS.